# (Notation/Definition) Little lp on a pointed metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition, banach-spaces

I am familiar with the $\ell^p$ spaces, but recently I've come across the following notion without explanation.  I looked it up on Wikipedia but I could not find the definition either.

Let $(X,d)$ be a (pointed) metric space.  What is meant by $\ell^p(X)$ *(here $p \in [1,\infty])$*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that $\ell^{p}(X)$ is the set of sequences $(x_{n})$ in $X$ such that
$$\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}d(b,x)^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty$$
where $b\in X$ is the special point of the pointed metric space $(X,d)$. (Note that $\ell^{p}(X)$ is dependent on $b$.)

Comment: So it is a free functor in this case?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough of category theory to answer that question.

Comment: No worries, but thank you very much for this clarification.  I appreciate it a ton!